# Tokenizing scientific notation in Antlr4 Lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

A vastly simplified version of my lexer rules (within a bigger grammar) are something like the following:

```
fragment HEX_DIGIT : [0-9A-F] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
SCIENTIFIC : 'E' [+-] ;
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
HEX_INTEGER : HEX_DIGIT+ ;
FLOAT_ZERO : '0'* '.' '0'+ ;
FLOAT : DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+ ;
```

The problem here comes with input such as `00E+00`. The tokens I would like out of this are '00', 'E+', '00'. However, Antlr goes the greedy route and parses '00E' as a HEX_INTEGER, and in the full lexer, produces '+' and '00' tokens.

Any suggestions for handling this special case in the lexer? `_input.LA()` tricks don't seem to work as we are operating at the character level, so I'm not always sure how far I have to look ahead to look for the special 'E+' sequence at the end of the hex number.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendations are:

1. Make `SCIENTIFIC` a fragment rule, and update your `INTEGER` rule to include support for scientific notation.

   ```
   INTEGER : DIGIT+ (SCIENTIFIC DIGIT+)?;
   ```
2. Update your `HEX_INTEGER` rule to not be ambiguous with `INTEGER`. For example, `777` could be an `INTEGER` or a `HEX_INTEGER`. Not all numbers contain the digit `a` through `f` in hexadecimal notation.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out after some trial and error, and hope it helps anyone else looking to do something similar. It turns out you can use semantic predicates at more than just the start of your lexer rules, which I didn't realize.

```
// Tricky, becuase of sci notation- can't catch something like 00E+00, as we
// need tokens like '00', 'E+', '00'. If our number ends in 'E', don't let it
// be followed by '+' or '-'.
HEX_INTEGER
    : HEX_DIGIT*
      {_input.LA(1) != 'E' && _input.LA(2) != '+' && _input.LA(2) != '-'}?
      HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```